# Selenium webdriver script fails to execute sendkey() in IE 8 when running it from jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have a selenium grid setup with the hub running on the CI (jenkins) server . Whenever I build and run my project from jenkins it fails to execute:

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"/Case/Add")]"));

inputElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

or rather selenium thinks that it did and moves on to the next command i.e `selenium.select("id=LifeOffice", "label=AMP");`

The nodes are virtual machines each running a different browser and this problem occurs only when the script is being executed on the IE 8 browser. When I run the script from my IDE its fine.

I have tried using `click ();` and  `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');",inputElement);` and I still have the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

This will sound strangely, but try to take a look on the page just after the sendkeys command. If the element is *just outside* or *just inside* the viewport, nearly touching the border, [this might have happened to you](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3602):

The element never got focus, because it's hidden behind the browser's scrollbar / statusbar / a piece of the page that covers it. Usually IE will scroll the element into the viewport and focus it, but sometimes, in the edge cases, it won't. And the `focus` (or clicks or anything) calls are then called on the statusbar / scrollbar / blank piece of page.

A workaround? I only know about two:

- change the computer's resolution / window size / IE layout (make it fullscreen, or disable the toolbars etc.)
- make sure you never change the resolutions / window sizes etc. and work with pure JavaScript in these edge cases:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", inputElement);
  ```

Comment: I had a very similar experience. Oddly it happened both on the Jenkins server and in my IDE. Locally, resizing the window made the problem go away. On the server I also resized the browser window, in the hope that it would change the default behaviour. But over the same period I also restarted both the Jenkins server and the server where the application was running, so it could be some combination of things that made the problem stop.