# selenium click and sendkeys fails at random on IE when using remotewebdriver

Tags: selenium, jquery-selectors, selenium-grid

I am using remote webdriver to drive an IE browser on a remote VM [ this is part of a grid setup]

I noticed that the click and sendkey events fails at random that is the session ends and the browser quits .This happens at different parts of the script it is not secluded to one area and occurs only when executing click and sendkey events .

Looking at the logs its looks like the event actually fired but did nothing and so when it moves to the next line it exits because it could not find the element.

I am using IE8 and the browser zoom is set to 100% . I have tried using JavaScriptExecutor with Jqueryselectors and got a javascript Exception hence I am forced to use click and send keys.

is anyone facing the a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with Remote Web driver running on an iPhone. It seems that the Remote Web driver doesn't support jQuery touch events, meaning that the JQuery is looking for a given number of touch events, ex. tap, touchstart, swipe etc. but Selenium is not triggering any of them when you call click. I resorted to using the following Javascript:

`window.jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(198,216)).trigger('touchstart');`

You can use `driver.findElement(By.id(id)).getLocation()` to get the location of the element you want to click.

I did however get an exception when I executed the Javascript:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'undefined' is not an object
>   Command duration or timeout: 530 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.2.1', revision: '16551', time: '2012-04-11 21:42:35'
>   System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.5', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:128)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:366)
>       at com.alea.qa.sample.CustomTouchAction.executeScript(CustomTouchAction.java:108)
>       at com.alea.qa.sample.CustomTouchAction.Touchstart(CustomTouchAction.java:76)
>       at com.alea.qa.sample.anotherRun.main(anotherRun.java:34)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: 'undefined' is not an object
>   Build info: version: '2.2.1', revision: '16551', time: '2012-04-11 21:42:35'
>   System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.5', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

But it still managed to click on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question and its (currently first and only) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444947/selenium-webdriver-script-fails-to-execute-sendkey-in-ie-8-when-running-it-fro), by user Slanec. It sounds similar. In short, try resizing your browser window. Elements near the edges can be inaccessible to Selenium drivers.